# Are there infinitely many natural numbers whose square root is rational?

Tags: radicals, rational-numbers

> True or false? There are infinitely many natural numbers $n$ for which $\sqrt{n}$ is rational.

Is this statement true/false? And how can I construct a proof of its statement or negation?

Comment: $0,1,4,9,\dots$: do you see a pattern?

Comment: God, I can't imagine why I never thought of that. Thanks @egreg

Answer (score 5):

Hint: can you see a pattern here?
$$
0,1,4,9,\dotsc
$$

Answer (score 3):

Try showing that there are infinitely-many natural numbers whose square root is a natural number. (It turns out that that's the only way for the square root of a natural number to be rational, but that's a side note.)

Answer (score 0):

Supose you have an infinite number of with of rationals q with the form q = a/b where a and b are integers and coprimes. So, q is rational.

But q^2 = a^2/b^2 is rational and sqrt (q^2) = a/b, so is true.